# How to see default MySQL parameter values of AWS MySQL RDS Instance on AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-rds

How to see default MySQL parameter values of AWS MySQL RDS Instance ?

I checked AWS RDS Console and didn't find any default value ?

[image: MySQL AWS RDS Doesn't show default values]

[image]

Edit

on looking [here][2] it shows : ( So should I follow this documentation?)
wait_timeout

```
Command-Line Format --wait-timeout=#
System Variable Name    wait_timeout
Variable Scope  Global, Session
Dynamic Variable    Yes
Permitted Values (Windows)  Type    integer
Default 28800
Min Value   1
Max Value   2147483
Permitted Values (Other)    Type    integer
Default 28800
Min Value   1
Max Value   31536000


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFRyl.png
  [2]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout
```

Comment: did you find an answer? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Default value of parameter depends on source fields.

- System: Amazon RDS service.
- EngineDefault: Source is the database engine;
- User: Parameter value came from the user

Source of `wail_time` parameter is `engine-default`. So as you say, you can follow the [mysql reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).